# IDE integration with GIT

Tags: git, ide, intellij-idea

We're considering migrating from CVS to GIT. Our whole development process is centered around IntelliJ, and the plugin we've found (GIT4idea) is severely lacking. Essential features, like global history logs or diff changes are completely missing.

Are there any other alternatives in IntelliJ land? And, if not, which current Java IDE do you consider to have the best GIT integration?

Comment: is there any specific reason for migrating to git? if not, I would suggest you seriously consider svn for once: it has a very mature set of tools and IDE integration plugins.

Comment: Probably SVN will be the one chosen after taking a look to the plugins alternatives

Comment: A key factor is also language/framework.  For instance if you are using ruby on Rails then IntelliJ's RubyMine has great git integration and git is also now de-facto in Ruby land.  Not sure if its adoption is spreading in other languages/frameworks.  svn (at least in ruby world) is yesterday's news - even outside startups ;)

Comment: Git-support should be much, much better in IntelliJ 11.

Answer (score 3):

Update January 2012

Off course, with latest Eclipse (3.6, 3.7+), as [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen) points out in the comments, **[EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/)** is now the official Git plugin for Eclipse and offers a quite complete set of Git feature right within Eclipse.

[image: Egit repos]

The EGit project is implementing Eclipse tooling on top of the [JGit Java implementation of Git](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) (much stable now).

---

Original answer July 2009:

We are using [JGit](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/EclipsePluginScreenshots) with Eclipse, but are finding the plugin not quite stable enough.

[image: JGit back in the days in 2009]

So basically, we have still a gitk running alongside our IDE... or we do have some scripts to encapsulate any operations not available through the IDE Git plugin.

Comment: For Eclipse 3.7 git support is good enough for daily work.  Supplement with command line git for corner cases.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I had forgotten about this old answer. I have updated its "status". EGit + JGit FTW now.

Answer (score 3):

**git-idea**

http://code.google.com/p/git-idea/

---

Next option is use GIT without IDE integration.

- Git-Gui or Tortoise GIT
- From command line

Comment: Why would you use GIT without IDE integration? You expect me to edit my code in terminal? Why not just edit in braille?

Answer (score 2):

I've found both the plugins for Netbeans and Eclipse lacking, some issues (sometimes nasty ones). Not stable enough for my taste, although Eclipse one is better.

I would recommend to just use command line. I know it's not the same, but should not be a big deal

Comment: +1; I've also found git IDE integration to be unilaterally terrible. At the same time, I've found Git to be worth-while when used outside of the IDE anyway, and preferable to a cleanly-integerated SVN client. Never liked CVS at all myself.

Comment: it is now more than 2 years later, and more or less the same story!

Comment: @kinjal the git client in Eclipse 3.7 is good enough for daily use.

Answer (score 0):

Now [git4idea](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=3033)(for IDEA), [nbgit](https://code.google.com/p/nbgit/)(for Netbeans), [egit](http://eclipse.org/egit/)(for Eclipse) are all mature plugins which provide excellent Git integration through [jgit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/). It is just a choice of which IDE you prefer to use.